# Lumen error on 'php artisan serve' command

Tags: php, laravel, memcached, lumen, laravel-artisan

I have installed Lumen using composer command. I'm getting an error while starting the server, the command is `php artisan serve`

Error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Class 'Memcached' not found
```

I have installed Memcached still, it's not working.

Comment: Have you installed the memcached pecl package? It is stated as a requirement in the Laravel docs for that cache driver. The lumen docs state that lumen uses the Laravel cache code.

Comment: I followed a tutorial to install, pecl was not mentioned over there. Can you share blog link or something where I can get all necessary information to install Memcached on mac os x?

Answer (score 3):

I have found that we can not use all Artisan commands with Lumen. `php artisan serve` command is only available for Laravel app to start the server. To start the Lumen app we have another command: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Comment: Maybe they should put that in the documentation... ?!?